# Show gif image on splash screen ios8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8

I have requirement of showing progress indicator on splash screen in my app.
This has to work from iOS 8+.
How to show progress indicator gif image on splash screen.Any ideas.Have tried to achieve in several ways as explained below.

1.Using launch screen option which was introduced in xcode6. but stil there is no assocciated .m file to customize it inorder to show progress indicator.

Comment: I have tried using new launch screen which was provided xcode 6.but was not successful.I can show static image but not gif image or progress indicator. Requirement is it has to work like how snapdeal app shows on launch screen.A loading indicator.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the LaunchScreen.xib and add an indicator but that will only be shown very briefly.

I would make a new view controller e.g. SplashViewController, containing your progress animation (even animated GIFs but I think you will have to use a uiwebview for that) and launch this upon startup. 
This way you can have control over how long you want it to be displayed.

And when you are done displaying it, kill it and start your app normally.

Comment: can you provide sample code snippet for that.Have already tried this but not successful

Comment: A basic example... You just call this method in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, do what you want (in my case I am loading settings from a server) and when you are done, switch to you main or app or wherever you want to go. 

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"StartFlow" bundle: nil];

SplashViewController *controller = (SplashViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplashViewController"];

UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];

self.window.rootViewController = nvc;

Answer (score 0):

You can use sequence of images to show your animation, here is code:

```
NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    //don't forget to add your images to images array

    animationImageView.animationImages = images;
    animationImageView.animationDuration = 1.0;
    //animationImageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:animationImageView];
    [animationImageView startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

Gif images don't play itself in UIImageView you need to use a category or something:

This one should do I think: https://github.com/mayoff/uiimage-from-animated-gif/

or If you want it as a progress hud you can use this one: [GiFHUD-Swift](https://github.com/cemolcay/GiFHUD-Swift)

EDIT: Also Giorgos is right you should use a new view controller or you can add a `UIImage` directly to the window for controlling the time duration of a splash screen. I have done it using this method in one of my app:

```
- (void)showSplashWithDuration:(CGFloat)duration
{
    // add splash screen subview ...

    UIImage *image          = [UIImage imageNamed:@"splash.png"];
    UIImageView *splash     = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    splash.frame            = self.window.bounds;
    splash.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
    [self.window addSubview:splash];


    // block thread, so splash will be displayed for duration ...

    CGFloat fade_duration = (duration >= 0.5f) ? 0.5f : 0.0f;
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:duration - fade_duration];


    // animate fade out and remove splash from superview ...

    [UIView animateWithDuration:fade_duration animations:^ {
        splash.alpha = 0.0f;
    } completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
        [splash removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

& you can call it in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions like this:

```
[self showSplashWithDuration:3.0];
```

Comment: Thanks Ajay.Have tried this.added splash.png to my project .it is showing black screen for specified duration 3.0.Not showing splash.png image.

Comment: I have tested just now it seems working fine  @Avilam

Comment: Still facing same issue.It would be great if you can post sample project in github and provide link

Comment: Here it is added some rough coding: http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=85289217751190743697